# Children divs not being sized equally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a four grid with different items for my web, however now all children divs have the same size:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid4">
        <input type="submit" name="input1" value="input1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid4">
        <input type="submit" name="input2" value="input2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid4">
        <input type="submit" name="input3" value="input3"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid4 no-border">
        <input type="submit" name="input4" value="input4"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
}

.grid4 {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(40,40,40,0.8);
    display: inline;
}

.no-border {
    border: none;
}
```

I tested it in jsfiddle and they indeed have the same size:

http://jsfiddle.net/ME7k8/

However, you can clearly see that the last chil div is smaller:

[image]

Why?! Any help?

**edit** In case it is too small in the image:

```
elemento {
}
.grid4 {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8);
    display: inline;
}
div {
    text-align: left;
}
body, div, td {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**edit** I checked again with the browser inspector and I can see that the first div is about 50% of the `.container` div. It has exactly the same css properties than the rest of the divs.

Comment: Because they're all the same size in the fiddle you posted, the problem must lie in something you haven't included in your question.

Comment: just look on the properties on the right of the image, it's all that's being loaded as CSS

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ME7k8/4/ now they are all the same width.

Comment: @DanielLisik yeah that's exactly what I tried in jsfiddle just copying from what I have in my web. Also check the new update.

Comment: I think the 3 first divs are wider due to the fact that you use `display:inline;`

Comment: @DanielLisik is right + the last div has no border so it is 2px less wide than the others

Comment: @web-tiki correct! :)

Comment: here they all have the same width : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ME7k8/5/

Comment: You can get them all to be the same size if you do basic words in each button saying input1, input2, input3, input4. However if you have varying character lengths in each button they will start to re-scale your grid because the button will grow in size to accommodate the length of the value= in the <input> field. Easy way to fix that is give a style class to the input field or make a generic one for all input fields.

Comment: It is helpful to state the question explicitly.
You want the items to BE the same width or not?
Saying "in this fiddle, the width is the same, but not in my app. I want my app to have the same width" goes a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 first divs are wider than the last due to:

**1.** They have the CSS `display:inline` (meaning their width gets effected by white-spaces, line breaks etc).

**2.** The last div has no border unlike the first 3.

### Give them identical width

So what you need to do to make sure all 4 divs have the same width is removing all white-space between the submit buttons and their parent divs, and also add `padding-right:22px;` to the last div (if you want the 4 divs *exactly* identical wide).

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ME7k8/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

I use your jdFiddle and put a blue background to see the difference, all divs have the same size, however, I declare a size for the container

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

and re adjust the size of the divs with the `grid4` attribute

```
.grid4 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.3%;
    border-right: 0.2% solid rgba(40,40,40,0.8);
    display: inline;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

when you put padding to each one (20px) that pixels are added to the "25%" of total size.. so this make it a bigger element, and probably that's the difference you couldn't see... with that on mind, may be you could solve your problem... [Check This...](http://jsfiddle.net/ME7k8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your last element has no border, while the others probably do.

Borders take up space, as do margin and padding.

Check out the box model by pressing ctrl + shift + i in your browser and hovering over an Also,
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

From inside to outside, there is padding, borderin, margin, outline.
The first three add size to your "box model". Outline does not.

If you specify a width or height, any padding, border, or margin will make your element not that specified width or height anymore. Needless to say, this makes for all kinds of headaches

One solution around this is to use box-sizing: border-box;
This makes specified padding and border actually be your specified width or height. Margin will still add to the dimension, which makes sense if you think about it.

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Also be sure to take care of prefixes so that it works on all browsers. 
You may not want to deal with this at this point, but check out the example in the last link, as well as caniuse.com.

If you don't want to handle cross browser support manually, there is a library to automatically post-process your CSS to add the appropriate prefixes. This uses the caniuse.com database so as long as you update this library, your post-processed css file will have the up to date prefixes without you having to worry about keeping up with browser versions or individual css feature deprecations.

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer
article on auto prefixing
http://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/